# Sequence with limit $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real strictly positive numbers. If $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=\infty$, is it necessary for the sequence to be strictly increasing? If not, give a counterexample.
Intuitively I think that it is true, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: How about $x_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\ 0 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \end{cases}$?

Comment: @Deshmukh Such $x_n$ has not limit $\infty$, maybe $n-1$ for $n$ even would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider for example

$$x_n=n+2\cos (n\pi)=-1,4,1,6,3,\ldots$$